# How to control ardrone in tum_simulator with command line?

Tags: control, ros, drone, tum-simulator, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed tum_simulator for ros indigo and am having some troubles controlling the drone. Ultimately I want to control the drone from a python program, so for now I would like to control it via the command line so as to ease compatibility with my python program.

I am having pretty simple troubles, mostly about stabilization. For example when I run

```
rostopic pub -1 /ardrone/takeoff std_msgs/Empty
```

the drone successfully takes off, but it never stops elevating.

How can I make the drone take off and stabilize itself at a certain altitude?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248260/how-to-control-ardrone-in-tum_simulator-with-command-line?/) by [frenchie007](https://answers.ros.org/users/28325/frenchie007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patricia](https://answers.ros.org/users/31744/patricia/) on 2017-09-11**:
Hi frenchie007,
I'm having the same problem, my guess it has something to do with sonar sensor..have you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator)? It tells you how to do exactly what you want. For example, in section 3.3.2 terminal command control, it says that to move around in the using the command line you simply publish `geometry_msgs/Twist` messages to the `/cmd_vel` topic. Here's the example that it gives

```
# fly forward
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'

# fly backward
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: -1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'

# fly to left 
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'

# fly to right 
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: -1.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'

# fly up 
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 1.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'

# fly down 
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -1.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'

# counterclockwise rotation
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 1.0}}'

# clockwise rotation
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: -1.0}}'

# stop
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

If this is too tedious for you (I wouldn't want to do it this way) you should follow the http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers or http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers tutorials and modify them so that when you press a key in the terminal (e.g. w => forward, s => backward, a => left, d => right, q => yaw counter clockwise, e => yaw clockwise) your node publishes the correct messages to move the quadcopter in the appropriate direction.

Also, check out Mike Hamer's excellent [AR.Drone tutorials](http://robohub.org/up-and-flying-with-the-ar-drone-and-ros-getting-started/). They're dated, but are still great examples on how to do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Caesar84](https://answers.ros.org/users/34428/caesar84/) on 2018-04-08**:
hi ,  I managed to fly it but i have little problem that is when sending a  fly to right `'{linear:  {x: 0.0, y: -1.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}' command it keeps going right and never stops. is there anyway other than sending 'Stop' after each single 'Move'  including take off

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-08**:
Not that I'm aware of. Using the command line for this is rather tedious and inefficient (from my experience). IMO you'd be better off writing a node to control the your drone.